# Finding a contradiction in equations and inequalities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, classical-mechanics

**Question:-**In the figure shown, Coefficient of friction between the blocks C and B is $0.4$. There is no friction between block C and ground.The system of blocks is released from rest in the shown situtation.Find the accelerations of masses.(Given $m_{B}=5kg , m_{C}=10kg , m_{A}=3kg$ )

[image]

I made two cases

$1)$ Block B and C move together.

$2)$ Block B and C will not move together.

When I solve equations for Case $1$, I find that block will move together.This implies that Case $1$ is true.

$$30-T=3a_{3}$$

$$T-f=5a_{5}$$

$$f=10a_{10}$$

$$f \leq 20$$

Note that if blocks B and C will move together then $a_{3}=a_{5}=a_{10}=a$

On solving we get $a=\frac {5}{3}m/s^2$ and $f=16.67N$

**As case $1$ is true. So contradiction condition must arrive during solving equations for case $2$.**

I got the following equations for case $2$.  **Despite my all efforts I was unable to find how equations will contradict**.

\begin{align}
30-T&=3a_{3}\\
T-f&=5a_{5}\\
f&=10a_{10}\\
f&\leq {20}\\
a_{3}&>a_{10}\\
\end{align}

Note that $a_{3}=a_{5}$

**My attempt**

Adding equation $1$ and $2$, we get

$$30-f=8a_{3}$$

So, $30-8a_{3}\leq 20$ and $10a_{10}\leq 20$

This gives $a_{3}\geq \frac54$ and $a_{10}\leq 2$

Also, $$T-f \geq \frac{25}{4}$$

$$30-T\geq \frac{15}{4}$$

This gives $T\leq \frac{105}{4}$

Adding eqation $1$ and $3$ we get

$$30+f-T=10a_{10}+3a_{3}$$

Using $f-T\leq \frac {-25}{4}$

$$12a_{3}+40a_{10}\leq {95}$$

Adding equation $2$ and $3$,we get

$$T=5a_{3}+10a_{10}$$

Using $T\leq \frac {105}{4}$

$$4a_{3}+8_{10}\leq 21$$

So We got following inequalities involving $a_{3}$ and $a_{10}$

> $$a_{3}>0$$
> $$a_{10}>0$$
> $$a_{3}>a_{10}$$
> $$a_{3}\geq \frac54$$
> $$a_{10}\leq 2$$
> $$12a_{3}+40a_{10}\leq {95}$$
> $$4a_{3}+8a_{10}\leq 21$$

On plotting them on graph where x-axis represents $a_{3}$ and y-axis represents $a_{10}$ I got quadrilateral having coordinates $(1.25,0), (1.25,1.25), (1.75,1.75), (5.25,0)$.

So, $1.25\leq a_{3} \leq 5.25$ and $0\leq a_{10}\leq 1.75$

Can anybody help to find contradiction.

Comment: This problem doesn't contradict the equations/inequalities for some values of the constants (i.e. $a_{3}=5$, $a_{10}=-1$, $T=15$, $f=-10$) so it can't be complete: are there further conditions on the constants?

Comment: There are no further conditions. May be I have written wrong equations.

Comment: The good news is that you didn't find a contradiction because there isn't one! Is the question from a book? Can you edit the post to give the full problem?

Comment: The equation is not for case 1). If B and C move at the same speed with the same acceleration, there's no friction between them.

Comment: @Oolong milk tea Why there should be no friction? Friction is the force that makes Block C move.

Comment: I was able to get bounds for $a_{3}$ and $a_{10}$ but that also doesn't help(I'll update my question)

Comment: @user1055 I just mean under your first assumption. Once there's relative movement, friction will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you have made a mistake. In either case we can calculate the frictional force directly, since we have friction at a maximum as we have motion:
$$F_\text{MAX}=\mu R=0.4\times5g=2g$$

I will calculate all accelerations below:

For B and A, let $a_1$ be their common acceleration. Resolve for A and then B:
$$\begin{align}
& 3g-T=3a_1\\
& T-2g=5a_1
\end{align}$$
Add the two equations together to eliminate $T$:
$$g=8a_1\implies a_1=\frac{g}{8}$$

This is actually equivalent to treating A and B as a single particle:

Using $F=ma$, it is clear that as the tensions cancel out we have
$$3g-2g=(3+5)a_1\implies g=8a_1\implies a_1=\frac{g}{8}$$

Now for box C. We have
$$2g=10a_2\implies a_2=\frac{g}{5}$$
where $a_2$ is the acceleration of C.

As an aside, we can prove that there is motion as follows:

First, note that the tension must be less than $3g$; otherwise A would move upwards, which is absurd. Now suppose that $T\le2g$. Then A will still accelerate downwards. But $F_\text{MAX}=2g$, so B will not move. This is a contradiction as B is connected to A. Hence $2g<T<3g$ and there is movement since $T>F_\text{MAX}$ as required.

Comment: @user1055 I am not assuming anything other than that there is movement, which is a fact. I have begun with the bare facts. Now, movement must be occurring as the greatest possible value of the friction is $2g$, whereas the weight of A is $3g$. Note that $3g>2g$. If you think of B and A as one particle then it is clear that the tensions cancel out, so as there is a resultant force in the towards the right for B and towards the ground for A there *must be acceleration and thus movement*.

Comment: @user1055 I understand what you are saying. Please read my previous comment carefully though. If you think of B and A as one particle it is clear that even when friction is at a maximum, forces are still unbalanced. Hence friction must be at a maximum, as their is definitely movement. Is that any clearer?

Comment: @user1055 I'm afraid that's incorrect. This imbalance of forces causes the accelerating. I will edit my answer to demonstrate the validity of this.

Comment: @user1055 You have misunderstood me; perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I never meant to compare weight to friction. I meant: think of the string as completely straight. In one direction, there is the $3g$  that was the weight of $A$ , In the other direction, we have $2g$ which was the frictional force. The tensions cancel out. Is that clearer?

Comment: Now i understand your answer. Here friction is kinetic friction not static friction(which I was assuming) . Also you should write this as $a_{C}>a_{A}$ this implies that case $2$ is false.

Comment: @user1055 Oh, now I understand what our area if confusion was! I've never learnt about static friction so I didn't even think that was bothering you. I'm glad I helped you. I hope I didnlt seem agressive when explaining my point of view to you; if I did please accept my apologies.